# laravel model $events not getting triggered

Tags: php, laravel, events, listener

I am creating a new Application on which when a article is created a notification will be show. I have tried using events and listeners.

My `App\Article.php`

```
...

protected $events = [

    'created' => Events\ArticleWasPublished::class

];

...
```

My `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php`

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\ArticleWasPublished' => [
        'App\Listeners\NotifyUsers',
    ],
];
```

My `App\Events\ArticleWasPublished.php`

```
...

use App\Article;

...

{

    public $article;

    public function __construct(Article $article)
    {
        $this->article = $article;
    }

...
```

My `App\Listeners\NotifyUsers.php`

```
use App\Notification;

...

public function handle(ArticleWasPublished $event)
{
    Notification::create([
        'article_id' => $event->article->id,
        'message' => 'A new Article was created'
    ]);
    var_dump('Something');
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

My problem is when a new article is created a new notification is not getting created. I am not even getting any errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I see, in Laravel 5.5 the property is named `$dispatchesEvents`, and not `$events`. Are you using this version?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events

It is one of the changes you need to do if you are migrating from an older version:

> Model $events Property
>
> The $events property on your models should be renamed to
>   $dispatchesEvents. This change was made because of a high number of
>   users needing to define an events relationship, which caused a
>   conflict with the old property name.

Comment: Yes, I am using Laravel 5.5 . Thank You for answering. It helped me :) . I was searching for this method in laravel event documentation and there I couldn't find one, there was only the way to manually listen.